# How can I find $\int(\sin ^4 x ) dx$?

Tags: integration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Evaluating $\\int P(\\sin x, \\cos x) \\text{d}x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29980/evaluating-int-p-sin-x-cos-x-textdx)

Hi,

My question is: How can I solve the following integral question?
$$\int(\sin ^4 x ) dx$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whoever answered this question might want to give a general answer to this "abstract duplicate": http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29980/evaluating-int-p-sin-x-cos-x-textdx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are standard techniques for solving integrals that consist of powers of sines and cosines.

One is to use [reduction formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_reduction_formulae) when you simply have a power of sines or a power of cosines. These can be obtained by performing integration by parts, followed by using a trigonometric identity. This is done in pretty much every single calculus textbook I have ever encountered.

Another is to use [trigonometric power reduction formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_identity#Power-reduction_formula) to change the fourth power of the sine into a sum of multiples of simple cosines, which can then be solved with an easy substitution.

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes handling trigonometric functions is easier in complex exponential form:

$$\sin ^4(x)$$
$$\frac{1}{16} \left(e^{-i x}-e^{i x}\right)^4$$
$$-\frac{1}{4} e^{-2 i x}-\frac{1}{4} e^{2 i x}+\frac{1}{16} e^{-4 i x}+\frac{1}{16} e^{4
   i x}+\frac{3}{8}$$
$$-\frac{1}{2} \cos (2 x)+\frac{1}{8} \cos (4 x)+\frac{3}{8}$$

Comment: @ Chris: I checked this and I did not get the same result, though I am unsure if the two are equal in some way. I got the following: $\frac {\rm 3x}{\rm 8}-\frac {\rm 1}{\rm 4}{\rm{\sin(2x)}}+\frac {\rm 1}{\rm 32}{\rm{\sin(4x)}}$.

Comment: Note that I did not integrate the expression.  I just rewrote it to make integration easier.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $$\int \sin^{n}  \ dx = -\frac{\cos(x) \sin^{n-1}(x)}{n}+ \frac{n-1}{n} \int \sin^{n-2}(x) \ dx$$ and $$\sin^{2}(x) = \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2} \cos(2x)$$

Comment: Note that the reduction formulas are typically not something one would *note* unless you've already seen them, in which case you probably have seen and know how to approach problems like the one posted.  The double-angle identities, on the other hand, are certainly helpful for this particular integral.

Answer (score 2):

This can be viewed as almost the same thing as exponential form, only in this case I assume that you remember multiple angles formula. (I.e. you do not need to use complex numbers.)
$\cos 4x=\cos^4 x- 6\cos^2x\sin^2x + \sin^4 x = (1-\sin^2x)^2-6(1-\sin^2x)\sin^2x+\sin^4x=\\=1-2\sin^2x+\sin^4x-6\sin^2x+6\sin^4x+\sin^4x-8\sin^4x-8\sin^2x+1$

$\cos 2x = \cos^2x - \sin^2x=1-2\sin^2x$

$\sin^4x=\sin^2x+\frac{\cos4x-1}8=\frac{1-\cos2x}2+\frac{\cos4x-1}8$

Comment: Answer on a PSQ