# Antiderivative of sec(x)

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Evaluating $\\int P(\\sin x, \\cos x) \\text{d}x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29980/evaluating-int-p-sin-x-cos-x-textdx)
>   [Ways to evaluate $\int \sec \theta \, \mathrm d \theta$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6695/)

Using Mathematica to get the antiderivative for sec(x), I get $$-\log(\cos\frac{x}{2}-\sin\frac{x}{2})+\log(\cos\frac{x}{2}+\sin\frac{x}{2}).$$

This doesn't look familiar, so, I'm thinking there's probably some identity or other way to transform this...

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: This falls under http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29980/evaluating-int-p-sin-x-cos-x-textdx

Comment: For $\sec(x)\tan(x)$, this is the derivative of $\sec(x)$. For $\sec(x)$ it's more complicated, but Weierstrass substitution works (in the worse case scenario).

Comment: @Arturo: I updated 29980 to include rational functions. I believe your current answer addresses that, but notifying you, just in case you think it might need editing.

Comment: @NateyG: No, there is no particularly simpler form, though some tables list it as $\log(\sec x + \tan x)+C$, $\log(\tan(\frac{x}{2}+\frac{\pi}{4})) + C$, or $\frac{1}{2}\ln|\sin x + 1| - \frac{1}{2}\ln|\sin x - 1| + C$.

Comment: The Antiderivative of $\sec(x)$ was already asked in this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6695/ways-to-evaluate-int-sec-theta-d-theta/6717#6717 "ways to evaluate integral sec"

Comment: Ah thanks. I need to do a better job of searching next time. ><

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}
\int\sec x\;dx
&=\int\sec x\cdot\frac{\sec x+\tan x}{\sec x+\tan x}\;dx
\\
&=\int\frac{\sec^2x+\sec x\tan x}{\sec x+\tan x}\;dx
\\
(\text{Letting }u=\sec x+\tan x&\text{ and }du=\sec x\tan x+\sec^2 x\;dx)
\\
&=\int\frac{du}{u}
\\
&=\log|u|+C
\\
&=\log|\sec x+\tan x|+C
\end{align}$$

Now, the output I get from Mathematica is:
$$\begin{align}
-\log(\cos\frac{x}{2}-\sin\frac{x}{2})+\log(\cos\frac{x}{2}+\sin\frac{x}{2})
&=\log\left(\frac{\cos\frac{x}{2}+\sin\frac{x}{2}}{\cos\frac{x}{2}-\sin\frac{x}{2}}\right)
\\
&=\log\left(\frac{(\cos\frac{x}{2}+\sin\frac{x}{2})^2}{(\cos\frac{x}{2}-\sin\frac{x}{2})(\cos\frac{x}{2}+\sin\frac{x}{2})}\right)
\\
&=\log\left(\frac{\cos^2\frac{x}{2}+\sin^2\frac{x}{2}+2\sin\frac{x}{2}\cos\frac{x}{2}}{\cos^2\frac{x}{2}-\sin^2\frac{x}{2}}\right)
\\
&=\log\left(\frac{1+\sin(2\cdot\frac{x}{2})}{\cos(2\cdot\frac{x}{2})}\right)
\\
&=\log\left(\frac{1+\sin x}{\cos x}\right)
\\
&=\log(\sec x+\tan x)
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

$\sec x\tan x=\frac{\sin x}{\cos^2 x}=-\frac{du}{dx}\frac{1}{u^2}$ where $u=\cos x$