# Integral u-substitution Problem

Tags: calculus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Evaluating $\\int P(\\sin x, \\cos x) \\text{d}x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29980/evaluating-int-p-sin-x-cos-x-textdx)

I'm given,  $$\int \sin^2(x) \,dx$$

I'm struggling finding the appropriate value for u to integrate using u-substitution.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: @Jonas Meyer @Moron @Akhil The difference between this question and the "duplicate" is that this is one specific question and it'd take someone a while to wade through that very long answer in the "duplicate" question to get to this part. The answer to that question is basically the same as a textbook section on this stuff, which the OP can probably see themselves by looking at a textbook. This guy needs help with this one specific question.  If you want to merge any questions that are somewhat similar, you might as well answer this type of question with "Read your textbook."

Answer (score 3):

$\sin^2 x = \frac{1 - \cos(2x)}{2}$.  Now you can integrate it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try thinking about your trig identities and whether you know anything that would make $sin^2(x)$ simpler before jumping to u-sub.