# How to evaluate $\int_0^{\pi/2}\;3\;\cos^2\theta\;d\theta$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\color{red}{3}\;\cos^2\theta\;d\theta$$

I tried doing it using $u$-substitution and then getting the anti-derivative. All in all, I keep getting $-1$, which is apparently wrong. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: That integral evaluates to a number.  It is not a function, unless you are thinking of it as a constant function of some unnamed variable.  So either there is nothing to differentiate, or you are differentiating a constant function, and in the latter case the answer is $0$.  As for the integral itself, the value is $3\pi/4$.  The identity $\cos(2\theta)=2\cos^2(\theta)-1$ is helpful for evaluating it.

Comment: Note that the value of the integral cannot possibly be $-1$: the function $f(\theta)=3\cos^2\theta$ is never negative, so the net area under the curve cannot be negative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Use the double-angle formula $\cos 2\theta=2\cos^2\theta-1$.  So $\cos^2\theta
=\frac{\cos 2\theta +1}{2}$.

I believe you mean to ask how does one *evaluate*, or *compute* the definite integral.

Answer (score 4):

There is a cute trick for this:

$$I = 3\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \cos^2 x \text{ dx} = 3\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sin^2 \text{ dx}$$

by using $\int_{a}^{b} f(x) \text{ dx} = \int_{a}^{b} f(a+b-x) \text{ dx}$

Adding gives us

$$2I = 3 \int_{0}^{\pi/2} (\cos^2 x + \sin^2 x) \text{ dx} = 3 \int_{0}^{\pi/2} 1 \text{ dx} = \frac{3\pi}{2}$$

Hence your integral is

$$ \frac{3\pi}{4}$$

But, there are more general methods which can be used. See the answers here: [Evaluating $\int P(\sin x, \cos x) \text{d}x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29980/evaluating-int-p-sin-x-cos-x-textdx)

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} 3 \cos^2\theta d\theta= \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \frac{3}{2}(1+\cos2\theta)d\theta$$
$$=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \frac{3}{2}+\frac{3}{2}\cos 2\theta d\theta$$
$$=\frac{3}{2}(\frac{\pi}{2}-0)+\frac{3}{4}(\sin2\frac{\pi}{2}-\sin 0)$$
$$=\frac{3}{4}$$

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, you can use integration by parts to find the antiderivative of $\cos^2 x$:
$$\eqalign{
\color{maroon}{\int\cos^2 x\,dx} =\int\underbrace{\cos x}_u\,\underbrace{\cos x\,dx}_{dv}&= 
 \underbrace{\cos x\vphantom{)}}_u\,\underbrace{( \sin x )}_{ v}-
\int\underbrace{\sin x\vphantom{)}}_v\,\underbrace{(-\sin x\,dx)}_{du}\cr
&=\sin x\cos x+\int\sin^2 x\,dx\cr
&=\sin x\cos x+\int(1-\cos^2 x)\,dx\cr
&=\sin x\cos x+ x-\color{maroon}{\int\cos^2 x \,dx};\cr
}
$$
Whence
$$
\int\cos^2 x\,dx={\sin x\cos x+x\over 2}+C.
$$

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest Wallis' formula

$\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0 \cos^n{x}$ $dx=\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0 \cos^n{x}$ $dx$

For $n$ even:

$\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0 \cos^n{x}$ $dx=\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0 \cos^n{x}$ $dx=\frac{1}{2}$x$\frac{3}{4}$x$...\frac{(n-1)}{n}$x$\frac{\pi}{2}$

For $n$ odd:

$\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0 \cos^n{x}$ $dx=\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0 \cos^n{x}$ $dx=\frac{1}{2}$x$\frac{3}{4}$x$...\frac{(n-1)}{n}$

$\therefore$ from this formula,

$3\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0 \cos^2{x}$ $dx=3(\frac{\pi}{4})$

Comment: Careful! This formula only works for limits $\frac{\pi}{2}$,$0$.

Comment: You probably mean Wallis' formula.

Comment: @Yves Daoust ,Its understood, isn't it? It is just a typo.

Comment: Typos in proper nouns deserve being fixed.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, To John Wallis, one of the most influential English mathematician before Isaac Newton. Your message is most welcome. I shall keep that in mind every time. Thank you.