# Integral of a trigonometric function

Tags: trigonometry, integration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Evaluating $\int P(\sin x, \cos x) \text{d}x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29980/evaluating-int-p-sin-x-cos-x-textdx)

How do I integrate the following function?
$$\frac{\sin 2x}{(1 + \cos^2x)^2}?$$

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $u = 1+\cos^2 x $. From here:

$du=-2\cos x \sin x dx= -\sin 2x dx$

Therefore:

$\int \frac{\sin 2x}{(1+\cos^2 x)^2 } dx = -\int \frac{du}{u^2}=-(\frac{1}{-1})u^{-1}+C=\frac{1}{u}+C=\frac{1}{1+\cos^2 x}+C$

Answer (score 0):

Use $\sin2x = 2 \sin x \, \cos x$ and substitute $\varphi = \cos x$.

Comment: Should be $\sin(2x) = 2\sin(x)\cos(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a substitution:
$$u=cos^2(x)$$
Then you obtaine the integral:
$$- \int \frac {1}{(1+u)^2}du$$
Now make a substitution:$s=u+1$ and then you have the result:
$$\int \frac{sin(2x)}{(1+cos^2(x))^2}=\frac{2}{cos(2x)+3}$$