# Integral $ \int \frac{dx}{\cos^3 x+2\sin(2x)-5\cos x}$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

$$
I\equiv \int \frac{dx}{\cos^3 x+2\sin(2x)-5\cos x}.
$$
This integral does have a closed form.  I am not sure where to start.  We can factorize the denominator as
$$
\cos^3 x+2\sin(2x)-5\cos x=(\cos^2 x+4\sin x-5)\cos x,
$$
but I am not sure where to go from there.  Thank you

Comment: We have very different definitions of fun it seems :)

Comment: @DepeHb All indefinite integrals are fun, all definite integrals are dangerous :)

Comment: So you are definite or indefinite?

Comment: @Awesome Haha, I am Definite Integral, although this post seems to show my cheating side as I am posting an indefinite integral ;)

Comment: I think that indefinite integrals are too intuitive to be fun. Although it can be for the teacher who just differentiated an arbitrary function in his head.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

We want to find
$$\int \frac{\cos x}{(\cos^2 x+4\sin x-5)(\cos^2 x)}\,dx,$$
or equivalently
$$\int \frac{\cos x}{(-\sin^2 x+4\sin x-4)(1-\sin^2 x)}\,dx.$$
The substitution $u=\sin x$ turns this into
$$\int\frac{-1}{(2-u)^2 (1-u^2)}\,du,$$
which yields (after a while) to partial fractions.

Comment: nice I didn't see that.  Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. Any rational function of $\sin t$ and $\cos t$ has a closed form antiderivative.

Comment: +1, in particular cases, such as this, an adequate particular substitution makes the computation faster than the Weierstrass substitution.

Answer (score 13):

The present integrand is a rational function (i.e. a ratio of two polynomials) of $\cos x$ and $\sin x$, which is considered a common question. So I take it partially from the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/29989/752) by Arturo Magidin to the question [Evaluating $\int P(\sin x, \cos x) \text{d}x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29980/evaluating-int-p-sin-x-cos-x-textdx) by Aryabhata, which is an entry of the [List  of Generalizations of Common Questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1868/752).

> #### Weierstrass Substitution
>
> A method that always works is [Weierstrass substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_substitution), which will turn such an integral into an integral of [rational functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_function), which in turn can always be solved, at least in principle, by the [method of partial fractions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fractions_in_integration).  This works even for *rational* functions of sine and cosine, as well as functions that involve the other trigonometric functions.
>
> Weierstrass substitution replaces sines and cosines (and by extension, tangents, cotangents, secants, and cosecants) by rational functions of a new variable. The identities begin by the trigonometric substitution $t = \tan\frac{x}{2}$, with $-\pi\lt x\lt \pi$, which yields
>   $$\begin{align*}
> \sin x &= \frac{2t}{1+t^2}\\
> \cos x &= \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}\\
> dx &= \frac{2\,dt}{1+t^2}.
> \end{align*}$$

Now we have

$$I =\int \frac{dx}{\cos ^{3}x+4\sin x\cos x-5\cos x}.$$

Using the substitution above we obtain:

\begin{eqnarray*}
I
&=&\int \frac{2}{\left( \frac{1-t^{2}}{1+t^{2}}\right) \left( \left( \frac{
1-t^{2}}{1+t^{2}}\right) ^{2}+4\frac{2t}{1+t^{2}}-5\right) \left(
1+t^{2}\right) }\,dt \\[2ex]
&=&\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{\left( 1+t^{2}\right) ^{2}}{\left( -1+t^{2}\right)
\left( t^{2}-t+1\right) ^{2}}dt,
\end{eqnarray*}

which can be integrated by the method of partial fractions:

\begin{eqnarray*}
I&=&\frac{1}{2}\int \left( \frac{2}{-1+t}-\frac{2}{9\left( 1+t\right) }-\frac{
1}{9}\frac{-5+16t}{t^{2}-t+1}-\frac{1}{3}\frac{-2+t}{\left( t^{2}-t+1\right)
^{2}}\right) dt \\[2ex]
&=&\ln (\left\vert -1+t\right\vert -\frac{1}{9}\ln \left( \left\vert
9+9t\right\vert \right) -\frac{4}{9}\ln \left( \left\vert
t^{2}-t+1\right\vert \right) +\frac{1}{6}\frac{t}{t^{2}-t+1}+C \\[2ex]
&=&\ln \left( \left\vert -1+\tan \frac{x}{2}\right\vert \right) -\frac{1}{9}
\ln \left( \left\vert 9+9\tan \frac{x}{2}\right\vert \right) -\frac{4}{9}\ln
\left( \left\vert \tan ^{2}\frac{x}{2}-\tan \frac{x}{2}+1\right\vert \right)
+\frac{1}{6}\frac{\tan \frac{x}{2}}{\tan ^{2}\frac{x}{2}-\tan \frac{x}{2}+1}
+C.
\end{eqnarray*}

PS. I've checked that the derivative of this last integral is

$$
\frac{1}{4}\frac{3\tan ^{2}\frac{x}{2}+\tan ^{6}\frac{x}{2}+3\tan ^{4}\frac{x}{2}+1}{\left( -1+\tan \frac{x}{2}\right) \left( 1+\tan \frac{x}{2}\right) \left( \tan ^{2}\frac{
x}{2}-\tan \frac{x}{2}+1\right) ^{2}},
$$

which is equal to

$$\frac{1}{\cos ^{3}x+4\sin x\cos x-5\cos x}.$$

Comment: Very nice AND detailed, complete solution.  Thank you

Comment: @Jeff You are welcome!