# Integrate $ \cos^3x \sin^2 x \ \text{d}x$

Tags: integration

$$\int \cos^3x \sin^2 x \ \text{d}x$$

I've simplified it to $\int \cos^3x-\cos^5x \,\mathrm{d}x$ using Pythagorean identities. It this the right way to do it? How do I integrate it from here?

Comment: Hint: put $y=\sin x$ in the original integral $(dy=\cos x\ dx)$

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29980

Answer (score 5):

Hint: Start with rewriting as
$$
\int \color{blue}{\cos^2(x)}\color{red}{\sin}^2(x)\color{green}{\cos(x)dx}
$$
Use that $\color{blue}{\cos^2(x) = 1 - \sin^2(x)}$. Now let $\color{red}{u = \sin(x)}$ so that $\color{green}{du = \cos(x)dx}$ (as Dario suggests in his comment above).

Answer (score 5):

$$
\int \cos^2 x \sin^2 x\ \underbrace{\Big(\cos x\,dx\Big)}_{\text{HINT}} = \int(1-\sin^2 x)\sin^2 x\ \underbrace{\Big(\cos x\,dx\Big)}_{\text{HINT}}
$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** 
As an alternative way, one can show that: $$\cos^3x\sin^2x=\dfrac1{16}\big(2\cos x-\cos(3x)-\cos(5x)\big).$$
Then you can easily integrate it since: $$\int\cos(ax)\,\mathrm dx=\dfrac{\sin(ax)}{a}+\text C.$$