# Integral of $\int\sin^{3}xdx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

In evaluating integral $\int\sin^{3}x dx $ I am pretty sure we need to use substitution $e^x=t$, but can't go  next step.

Comment: Why would you substitute $e^x$ when you have nothing like it in the integral? Wouldn't it help to rather substitute some trigonometric term?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Evaluating $\int P(\sin x, \cos x) \text{d}x$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29980/evaluating-int-p-sin-x-cos-x-textdx)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$\sin^3 x \,dx = \sin^2 x \sin x = (1 - \cos^2 x) \sin x$$

Let $u = \cos x\implies du = -\sin x$.

That gives us: 
$$\int \sin^3 x \,dx = -\int (1 -u^2)\,du = \int (u^2 - 1)\,du$$

Answer (score 1):

Use this trignometric identity

$$\sin 3x=3\sin x-4\sin^3 x$$

$$\therefore \sin^3 x=\frac{3\sin x - \sin 3x}{4}$$

I think you can proceed from here.

Answer (score 1):

$$ \int\sin^{3}x~dx =\int \left( \dfrac{3\sin x-\sin 3x }{4}\right) ~dx =\dfrac{3}{4}\int \sin x~dx-\dfrac{1}{12}\int \sin 3x~d(3x)\\=-\dfrac{3\cos x}{4}+\dfrac{\cos 3x}{12}+C $$

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the substitution you suggested, but you might have success if you use $\sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x) = 1$ so that $\sin^2(x) = 1 - \cos^2(x)$.  Then this changes your problem:

$$\int \sin^3(x) \, dx = \int \sin(x) \, dx - \int \cos^2(x) \sin(x) \, dx$$

These two new integrals should be easier.