# Prove that the integral of $\sin^2(x)/(5+3\cos(x))$ from $0$ to $2\pi$ is $2\pi/9$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, residue-calculus

I'm not really unsure of how to approach this problem. I was thinking of reparametrizing the sin and the cos to its exponential form but I realize that it becomes even messier and leads sort of nowhere.  There are no singularities for this function f(x) I believe, so there's not really a way to use the Residue theorem either.  Can anyone give me some help on this?

Comment: Did you try dropping $\sin^2x$ into double angle formula for $\cos x$?

Comment: Yea, I think it gets really nasty as well.

Comment: I would go with half-angle tangent substitution, but I'm too tired to do this now.

Comment: Can you show me how that might work out?  I guess it might be a mistake on my end.

Comment: there will actually be singularities on the complex plane $5+3cos(z)=0$ does have a solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Evaluating $\int P(\sin x, \cos x) \text{d}x$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29980/evaluating-int-p-sin-x-cos-x-textdx)

Comment: @epimorphic A definite integral over $[0,2\pi]$ can be computed in ways that do not require an antiderivative.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Using half-angle tangent substitution $u=\tan(\dfrac{x}{2})$ and with some algebra you find:
$$
4\int \dfrac{u^2}{u^6+6u^4+9u^2+4} dx =4\int \dfrac{u^2}{(u^2+1)^2(u^2+4)} dx
$$

Now use partial fractions.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose we seek to evaluate
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\sin^2 x}{5+3\cos x} dx.$$

Put  $z   =  \exp(ix)$  so  that   $dz  =  i\exp(ix)  \; dx$  and  hence
$\frac{dz}{iz} = dx$ to obtain
$$\int_{|z|=1}
\frac{(z-1/z)^2/4/(-1)}{5+3/2(z+1/z)} \frac{dz}{iz}
\\ = -\int_{|z|=1}
\frac{(z-1/z)^2}{20+6(z+1/z)} \frac{dz}{iz}
\\ = -\int_{|z|=1}
\frac{z^2-2+1/z^2}{20+6z+6/z} \frac{dz}{iz}
\\ = -\int_{|z|=1}
\frac{z^4-2z^2+1}{20z^2+6z^3+6z} \frac{dz}{iz}
\\ = -\frac{1}{i} \int_{|z|=1}
\frac{1}{z^2} \frac{z^4-2z^2+1}{6z^2+20z+6} \; dz.$$

There  are three  poles, one  at $z=-3$,  another one  at  $z=-1/3$ and
another one at $z=0.$ Only the latter two contribute.

The pole at $z=-1/3$ is simple and hence the residue is
$$\left.\frac{1}{z^2}
\frac{z^4-2z^2+1}{12z+20}\right|_{z=-1/3}
= \frac{4}{9}.$$

The remaining contribution is from
$$\int_{|z|=1}
\frac{1}{z^2} \frac{1}{6z^2+20z+6} \; dz
=\frac{1}{6}
\int_{|z|=1}
\frac{1}{z^2} \frac{1}{z^2+10/3z+1} \; dz
\\ =\frac{1}{6}
\int_{|z|=1}
\frac{1}{z^2} \sum_{q\ge 0} (-1)^q z^q (z+10/3)^q \; dz.$$

The only contribution in the series is from $q=1$ and it is
$$-\frac{1}{6} 10/3 = -\frac{5}{9}.$$

Collecting everything we get
$$-\frac{1}{i} \times 2\pi i\times
\left(\frac{4}{9}-\frac{5}{9}\right)
= \frac{2\pi}{9}.$$

Comment: @cambelot this, by the way, is a fairly standard way to use the residue theorem.  Whenever you're taking an integral of a function over its period, this substitution lets you recast the problem as a residue calculation.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: use that $$\sin(x)=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}$$
$$\cos(x)=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$$
$$dx=\frac{2dt}{1+t^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Just like the answer above that star with "Suppose we seek to evaluate ..."

Then, at the pole z=0, derivate once, in order that the residue evaluation do not colapse at the limit z=0.

This procedure is explained in "Mathematical Methods in the Physical Sciences", by Mary Boas. Chapter Functions of a complex Variable, section: 'evaluation of definite integral by use of the residue theorem'.