# Help on integrating a rational function of sine and cosine.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I got stuck while trying to integrate this function, I've tried to make a new function so that I can solve the integral with a system of equations, but I couldn't get an answer.
Here's the function $h(x)=\frac{8sin(x)+3cos(x)}{sin(x)+2cos(x)}$, and I am trying to calculate $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} h(x) dx$
I'd appreciate any help on this.

Comment: try multiplying both the numerator by $\sec^3(x)$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29980/evaluating-int-p-sin-x-cos-x-textdx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the idea is to split the integrand $\frac{8\sin x+3\cos x}{\sin x+2\cos x}$ into two parts, both of which will be easy to integrate. One of those, clearly, should be a multiple of $1=\frac{\sin x+2\cos x}{\sin x+2\cos x}$. The other? Well, it would be nice if we could just substitute $\sin x+2\cos x$. That works when the numerator is the derivative $\cos x - 2\sin x$, or a multiple of that.

So, there's our system:
$$8\sin x+3\cos x=a(\sin x+2\cos x)+b(-2\sin x+\cos x)$$
Equate coefficients for
$$a-2b = 8$$
$$2a+b = 3$$
Can you finish it from there?

Comment: Yes, that works for me.